# npm i fails with error message?

Tags: javascript, npm

I try to config envirenment for launch tests on js.
Windows10, python 2.7

After input command npm -i I have error message:
[image]

I tried to use npm install --global --production windows-build-tools

Comment: react is installed?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou sorry, the same error mesage after instal react

Comment: Do you have latest version of npm? Also try to update node-gyp from same dir : npm install node-gyp

Comment: C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install node-gyp, you need to do that from a Command Prompt with Administrator privileges. Right click on cmd and do "run as administrator"

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the react, if you check closely the error 'npm WARN react-markdown@3.4.1 requires a peer of react@^15.0.0 ...'

```
npm install react --save
```

Also, you may try upgrading your react-native install. react-native is as v0.30.0 now

```
npm update react-native
```